# Solve $ \cos 2x - \sin x +1=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve $ \cos 2x - \sin x +1=0$ for $0\leq x \leq 360$ and not having much luck.

In my attempts I've been substituting $1-2 \sin^2 x$ in place of $\cos 2x$ and I've tried to work it out from there but haven't really got anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you had trouble with? If you substitute $\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2x$ your equation becomes

$$2\sin^2x + \sin x = 0$$

which is much easier to solve.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Thanks for the response, in my quest to get an answer I made a silly typo. It should be a +1 at the end rather than a -1.

Comment: @shaun Thanks for that link, I'll edit my question asap.

Comment: I don't know why the wrong edit got approved. Thanks for changing it back, Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to use the following identity is a good one:
$$\cos(2x)\equiv 1-2\sin^2{x}$$
Then, you obtain the following:
$$1-2\sin^2{x}-\sin{x}+1=-2\sin^2{x}-\sin{x}+2=0$$
The trick here is to substitute $u=\sin{x}$, and this gives a quadratic equation:
$$-2u^2-u+2=0 \implies 2u^2+u-2=0$$
You can now use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! It hadn't occurred to me to use the quadratic formula here so would probably have been stuck on that question all night.